# Какую СУБД и библиотеку (для запросов к БД) на node js выбрать?

Tags: база-данных, node.js

Занимаюсь изучением web разработки. Нужно сделать правильный выбор. Понимаю, что в коммерческих проектах используют в основном sql, если это не так поправьте меня. Хочется понять, что сейчас актуально либо более востребовано?

Сайт: блог, с небольшим количеством товара, новостной ленты, авторизацией, и онлайн оплатой.

Comment: Выбор БД зависит от деталей конкретного проекта

Comment: Выбор зависит от того что сейчас более востребовано (что бы было больше шансов на собеседовании), и для работы через node.

Comment: А какого рода работа вас интересует ? Сайты делать с небольшими и средними нагрузками ? Ну тогда MySQL, просто потому что она есть практически на любом хостинге. Хотя для нормальной работы я бы ее не брал. Выбор БД зависит от природы данных с которыми надо работать. Если они реляционны, то берут SQL, какой конкретно зависит от предпочтений компании, иногда от более глубоких нюансов данных. А если данные не структурированы - то NoSQL решения. А иногда и то и другое одновременно в рамках одного проекта, для разных целей

Comment: Добавил пример с описанием сайта, так сможете конкретней ответить?

Comment: На описанное, к сожалению, MySQL. Хотя на чистой ноде в наше время никто такого не делает, берут какую нибудь CMS или фреймверк, а они скрывают БД за таким слоем абстракций, что вообще не имеет значения где они хранят данные. И часто с ними БД меняется парой строчек к конфиге, а код этого даже не замечает

Comment: И с такой работой, когда вы придете в компанию на работу у вас с порога спросят с какими CMS вы работаете. Потому что на CMS такое делается не программистом за пару дней

Comment: Спасибо полезная информация.

Answer (score 0):

Если верить опросникам из интернетов, то самая распространенная БД на данный момент это **SQL**. Если начинать изучение БД - я бы рекомендовал начать именно с MySQL.

Среди именно нереляционных БД, то это **MongoDB**.

В любом случае не лишним будет ознакомится обеими вариантами, чтобы понимать недостатки и приемущества той или иной базы данных